# Building image for QSPI flash memory

Tags: linux, boot, embedded, yocto

I am working with development board which runs Linux system built in Yocto. I boot the board from the SD card. My boot partition has three files: `BOOT.bin` (bootstrap), `u-boot.bin` and `u-boot.env`. I would like to boot my board from the QSPI memory. I can upload a `BOOT.bin` file to QSPI and when I power on the board I see that the `bootstrap` is started. But when I created and uploaded to QSPI memory an image that has one `fat` partition (boot) nothing is happens when I turn on my board.

Why can the device boot when I directly upload the `bootstrap` binary to the memory, but cannot boot when I upload the partition with the same `bootstrap` file?

Comment: What board is this? How/when is the QSPI mapped into the address space, if at all e.g. for "execute in place" (XIP)? How is the (QSPI) flash partitioned? We need more details, but as a quick guess your partitioned image with the FAT filesystem on it is probably not correct for QSPI flash, which is likely to be different to the SD card partitioning ...